# Covariance of linear combinations of correlated random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance, linear

I am trying to predict the covariance of two linear combinations of normal random variables:
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal N}$
\begin{align}
X &= w\N(u_1,\sigma^2_1)+(1-w)\N(u_2,\sigma^2_2)  \\
Y &= w\N(u_1,\sigma^2_1)+(1-w)\N(u_3,\sigma^2_3)
\end{align}
where $w$ can range from $0$ to $1$.

I've tried solving for $\text{cov}(X,Y)$ using
\begin{align}
\text{cov}(X,Y) &= \text{E}(XY) - \text{E}(X)\text{E}(Y) \\  
\text{cov}(X,Y) &= \text{corr}(X,Y)\sigma_X\sigma_Y
\end{align}

but am not sure how to find $\text{E}(XY)$ in the first case and $\text{corr}(X,Y)$ in the second.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Thanks for the information. No, this isn't for a course, I'm trying to apply this to a research study.

Comment: Is your model: $X = w A + (1-w) B$; $Y=w A + (1-w) C$, where A, B, and C are all uncorrelated?  If so, $cov(X,Y) = w^2 \sigma^2_1$ .

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Could I also ask about the more complicated case, where A, B, and C are not all uncorrelated? E.g., the same overall model for X and Y, but where A = kB + (1-k)C?

Comment: @Matt P Expand out the covariance into a sum of terms, as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties .  Then simplify each term.  In your original version, 3 out of 4 additive terms came out to zero.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone ok I think this should be it: $\sigma(X,Y) = w^2 \sigma^2_A + w(1-w)(1-k) \sigma^2_C + w(1-w)k \sigma^2_B\\var(X) = w^2\sigma^2_A +2w(1-w)k \sigma^2_B + (1-w)^2 \sigma^2_B \\ var(Y) = w^2\sigma^2_A +2w(1-w)(1-k) \sigma^2_C + (1-w)^2 \sigma^2_C $

Comment: The hyphen at the end of the first line is a display error

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

\begin{align*}
cov(aX+bY, cV + dW) &= E[acXV + adXW + bcYV + bd YW]\\
&-E[aX+bY]E[cV+dW]\\
&= acE[XV]+adE[XW]+ bcE[YV] + bdE[YW]\\
&- acE[X]E[V]-adE[X]E[W]-bcE[Y]E[V]-bdE[Y]E[W]\\
&= ac \times cov(X,V) + ad \times cov(X,W) + bc\times cov(Y,V) + bd \times  cov(Y,W) 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

w is a constant ranging from 0 to 1.

Let P~ N(u1,σ21), Q ~ N(u2, σ22) and R~ N(u3, σ23)]

If variables P, Q, and R are independent, then

Cov (X, Y) = Cov [w*N(u1,σ21)+(1−w)*N(u2, σ22), w*N(u1,σ21)+(1−w)*N(u3, σ23)]

= Cov [w*P + (1-w)* Q,  w*P + (1-w)*R]

= w2*Cov(P, P) + w*(1-w)*Cov(P, R) + + w*(1-w)*Cov(Q, P) +  (1-w)2*Cov(Q, R)

= w2* σ21  [If variables  P, Q, and R are pair-wise independent]

Alternately, by using Cov(X, Y) =E(XY)−E(X)E(Y)

Cov (X, Y) = Cov [w*P + (1-w)* Q,  w*P + (1-w)*R]

= E[w2*P2 + w*(1-w)*PR + + w*(1-w)*QP + (1-w)2*QR] – 
E[w*P + (1-w)* Q]* E[w*P + (1-w)*R]

= w2*E(P2) + w*(1-w)*E(PR) + + w*(1-w)*E(QP) + (1-w)2*E(QR)
-[w*u1 + (1-w)*u2]* [w*u1 + (1-w)*u3]

= w2*E(P2) - w2*u2

[If variables  P, Q, and R are pair-wise independent, then E(XY) = E(X)*E(Y)]

= w2* σ21

Note: if the variables P, Q and R are not independent, then we would require more information regarding the co-variance/correlation between them.

Comment: Please use math markup, $\LaTeX$, See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference